# Why can't I log in to my storefront?

Tags: b2b-commerce, b2b

When I try to access by login to experience as a user for b2b storefront it does not open. Instead, page shows message as forbidden

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've fixed the formatting issues for you. One thing to note is that while you do have 2 different image urls here, they appear to be the same image. Did you intend for one of them to show the error message you're getting? At any rate, please [edit] your question to include the error message _as text_ and _verbatim_ (i.e. do not try to shorten or paraphrase the error). Text is easier to search and is more accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forbidden can be a couple of things, I'd suggest start by looking into the Permissions assigned to the Community User License:

- Ensure they have the correct CRUD access to the necessary Objects
- Check they are associated to the correct Buyer Group(s)
- Profile permissions have been defined properly

If you can't see anything obvious I'd suggest following [this](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/b2b_standalone_setup.pdf) to confirm you have done all of the necessary setup steps

Comment: Thanks Tim its working

Comment: Also getting issue prices are not reflecting any ideas..??

Comment: I had fun with pricing when I started setting up the shops, I've found it to be a bit temperamental at times, a small change can affect a lot. Best way to go about it is to check the Pricebook that is connected to the store to confirm that it has the correct Pricebook Entries, then check each Pricebook linked to the Buyer Groups, associated to the Buyer Account to ensure the Entries are correct there as well. You can the Pricebook with the Original Prices under Administration > General Settings, there you can also see the Pricing Strategy, that will affect how the pricing is displayed as well